# How to add commas / delimiters for all list items except last?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Say I have a for loop, which lists a bunch of Users.  There might be 0-n Users in the loop.  I want to put commas after each User name except the last one.

So for:

```
<p>
{% for u in users %}
{{u.name}},
{% endfor }
</p>
```

I get:

```
Sam, Neil, Bob,
```

I want:

```
Sam, Neil, Bob
```

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64387576/5058564

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree join is a good approach. If you want to do it with for, try

```
{% for u in users %}
{{u.name}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor }
```

Comment: `{{ u.name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% else %}.{% endif %}` if you want a "." at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop in Django 1.2 includes a few automatically generated variables. Among those are:

```
forloop.first
forloop.last
```

So you could place the delimiter using an if statement:

```
<p>
{% for u in users %}
{{u.name}}
{% if not forloop.last %}
,
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to loop, and you just have a list, then 'join' is probably your best solution.

But first we need to get a list of all names, map should help us with that, then join all the results:

```
{% with names = map(lambda u: u.name, users) %}
{{ names|join:", " }}
{% endwith %}
```