# Django loop – remove last comma

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have the following loop set up, but need to remove the comma on the last item (it's to replicate a JSON array for cycle2)

```
{% for product_in_series in series.get_products %}{%spaceless%}
    {% with product_in_series.product as product %}
    {%if not forloop.first%}
            "<img src='{% version product.get_overview 'page_image' %}'>",
    {%endif%}
    {% endwith %}
{%endspaceless%}{% endfor %}
```

Cheers,
R

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this?

```
{% for product_in_series in series.get_products %}{%spaceless%}
    {% with product_in_series.product as product %}
    {%if not forloop.first%}
        "<img src='{% version product.get_overview 'page_image' %}'>"
        {%if not forloop.last%},{%endif%}
    {%endif%}
    {% endwith %}
{%endspaceless%}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
{{ forloop.last|yesno:",&#44;"|safe }}
```

`&#44;` - is a comma

Answer (score 3):

None of the above works for me.
The correct syntax, as in Django 3.0, is as such

```
 {% with querythisandthat as A %}
   {% for  u in A %}  {{ u.interesting_stuff }} 
      {% if u == A.last %} . {% else %} ; {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
 {% endwith %}
```

The reason is that A.last is not True/False, but it is the last element of the queryset

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first